# Can i keep my Object in memory till application exits?

Tags: ios, memory-management, abaddressbook, cncontactstore

I am using Native contact to store in `NSMutableDictionary`.
So whenever required i can query any contact from `NSMutableDictionary` without going to Native API's (`ABAdressBookRef`, `CNContactStore`).

My Concern is how long `NSMutableDictionary` will be available in memory?.

Comment: Define a singleton, and place your Dictionary on it, it will last till you terminate the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you hold a strong reference to it somewhere. When there are no strong references to it, it will be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton class with any number of properties that you want to keep them a live during app time , edit , read them from anywhere in the app